# Test dependencies for white-box unit testing Java modules with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, java-module

I'm trying to convert existing Java projects with Maven and Eclipse into Java 9+ modules. The projects have unit tests and the unit tests have test dependencies. I need the test dependencies to be available in the test code, but I don't want them exposed to the rest of the world in the published modules.

I think [Testing in the Modular World](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world.html) describes the Maven solutions well. In summary one solution is to create one `module-info.java` in the main source folder and another in the testing folder. The file in the main folder has the real dependencies. The file in the test folder adds the test dependencies.

The solution works well in Maven and I can build and run tests from the command line. However, when I import the project into Eclipse as a Maven project it balks. Eclipse complains that "build path contains duplicate entry module-info" and refuses to build the project at all.

Using the other suggested solution in the article with a `module-info.test` containing `--add-reads` has no effect and the build fails in both Maven and Eclipse as the tests can't find their dependencies.

To make matters more complex I need to import the test dependencies from Maven, but I also need to import standard Java modules that are not used by the main code. For example one unit test relies on the built-in web server provided by `java.httpserver` and as it is part of the JDK any magic done on the test dependencies will miss it.

Is there a solution for this that works in Maven and Eclipse (latest versions)? It sounds like a very common problem and the module system has been around for a while by now.

Note that I really don't want to change the project settings in Eclipse. I can fiddle with plugins in the pom files, but adding a manual routine where all developers need to edit the generated/imported project settings manually is not an option.

EDIT:
There is an open Eclipse bug report for this, see [Eclipse bug 536847](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536847). It seems it is not supported yet, but perhaps someone can suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse emulation of the multiple-classpaths-per-project feature in Maven has been broken for very long.    The symptom is that you can have non-test classes using test dependencies just fine.

Essentially Eclipse just considers each project to have a single classpath instead of two parallel ones which causes things like this to ... not do the right thing.

I would suggest splitting each of the problematic projects into two.  One with the actual sources and one with the test sources (depending on the actual source).  This will avoid the Eclipse bug and also allow you to use the newest version of Java for your tests while having your application built for an older version of Java.

Comment: That works for integration tests and black box unit tests, but it breaks down if the tests need to be in the same package as the tested classes to access internals, at least when using the module system. Plus it means the first Maven project can build successfully even if the tests in the second fail. I've negative experiences with that and would like to keep the tests in the main project.

Comment: Then I would recommend switching away from Eclipse. The best IDE for the moment for Java is IntelliJ and the free community edition should be able to do this.

Comment: Well, personally I could do that, but here we need to support both or at least Eclipse which is the company standard.